# Slow internet slows my computer?

Tags: windows, performance, internet-speed

For some reason, when I connect to my school internet my computer's speed slows drastically for certain things, such as opening applications, loading websites and even things like clicking buttons that are part of windows. Being offline is fine, and so is my home internet. Is it because of some kind of school tracker/app or am I just imagining things? Also not everything is slow, like apps run fine they just take extremely long to do things like load menus.

Also weirdly it seems to only happen to me? I've asked some other people and they just get confused or laugh at me...

I am using a laptop with windows 10 with a RTX 3070 and 24GB of memory and an intel core i7.

I've had this issue ever since high school which makes you use their internet. And yes, mobile hotspot works fine. Right now I am using a new laptop because recently my old one's motherboard failed but the one I have now is just a better version of my old one, which had the same speed issue. I also had a mac book air at the start of high school which broke, but I'm pretty sure it didn't have the issue.

Comment: It should not make a difference.  You need to ask your school if they are loading an App for you to use their Internet.

Comment: Okay. I haven't intentionally downloaded anything except microsoft office and teams. To access the internet however I have to sign into a captive portal.

Comment: Captive Portal is what I meant by school app and you need to ask them about this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John how could 802.1X impact local machine speed?

Comment: If the portal adds an app - that is what I am thinking.  Plain internet should not cause this issue, but added school apps in the portal might. So I say - ask the school.

Comment: DNS is slow. Windows does a lot of looking up URL's in the background thanks to alll the search integration with the web. It's not uncommon for DNS being slow to really make windows chug. 

Failing that check task manager's performance tab. It could be some weird issue with lots of ARP and other broadcast traffic causing issues with your network driver or firewall/anti-virus solution. I've seen this before as well and the problem process shows up in task manager pretty quickly.